# how do I to add catel to a prism 8 wpf app

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, catel

Has anyone tried integrating [catel](https://github.com/Catel/Catel) with [prism 8](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism).
[Orc.Prism](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Prism) supported prism 5 and 6 and could bem modified to support prism 7 but now the Bootstrapper has been removed from prism 8.
How can I modify my [PrismApplicationBase](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/src/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/PrismApplicationBase.cs) decendant to support catel.

Comment: When I converted my older Prism app to the new one it was pretty straightforward.  Most of the Bootstrapper logic just moved to virtual functions in the app.  I don't remember it being very difficult to figure out.    I'll admit to not being familiar with Catel.  Is it Prism aware?  Does it expose its own application object or Bootstrapper?

Comment: It has it's own [Bootstrapper](https://github.com/WildGums/Orc.Prism/blob/develop/src/Orc.Prism.Shared/BootstrapperBase.cs).

Comment: I think the question should be how to add catel to a prism 8 app.